# duel boot 2006 imac with mac os and xubuntu freezes constantly, and lubuntu wont install properly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu, lubuntu, mac

so i followed a guid to make a modified 64 bit xubuntu distro that works with systems that have a 32 bit efi, it boots up and the desktop works fine, i can move as much as i want and it works flawlessly. The problem comes when I open any application, I have a minimum of an instant freeze and a maximum of maybe 10 seconds, I have tried deleting the partitions and reinstalling multiple times to no avail. My mac model is a imac 6,1 (or the late white imac) with upgraded ram (up to 6gb), the distro is xubuntu 18.4, I also tried to install lubuntu, it didnt crash and downloaded fine, the issue was it wouldn't boot off of my hard disk without the install disk. Meaning that it was running the live environment so I couldn't install anything onto it.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you don't have faulty hardware?  Have you run memory tests, done a *cap-scan* & checked of your hardware is reliable (including PSU or power supply). Computers tend to be consistent, and freezing without clue makes me think of capacitors.. For help with Lubuntu you'll need to be specific, did you verify ISO, validate the write to your media (for *unstated* version). In Xubuntu did you start apps from terminal to view messages (computers will be consistent unless cap/psu issues) and what were those messages. Did SysRq keys work on freeze? or switching to text terminal? etc

Comment: FYI: my comments are brief, but by providing all details & messages, it helps us understand & provide helpful responses. I would have expected messages on the Lubuntu install, but I don't know your tried release so I can't even know what messages you may have gotten (3 different installers are currently supported for Lubuntu; you've given no clues as to which you used, no release details, no ISO details). By running an app at terminal, you'd see the same messages for freeze generally (crash message anyway given time varies a little), if you they weren't consistent it's likely hardware

Comment: The verson of lubuntu was 16. Something, I do t have the computer with me currently because I’m not at my house, and the freezes don’t have an error message, I can still move my mouse and it’s not just the computer being slow because I have left it for hours and it doesn’t move. Also because of how common gpu fails are in this Mac I wouldn't be surprised if that is the issue, and I installed both lubuntu and xubuntu with a iso burned onto a CD with simply burns, the message with lubuntu is something like no bootable disk, please insert mound disk

Comment: Ubuntu server & desktop releases are *year.month* in format, and only specialist releases like Ubuntu Core 18 use the *year* format (they have no desktop, don't use *deb* packages being *snap* only). Lubuntu being a desktop release is always *yy.mm* in format. Also if you can still move the mouse, the system isn't frozen (your GUI maybe, so switching to terminal, or SysRq commands will still work).

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: I can’t open anything or do commands either, I have tried ctrl alt del, alt f4, and more none work

Comment: If the mouse moves; SysRq commands will work (they go directly from keyboard to linux kernel; even through a frozen GUI or no terminal (even when mouse is dead; your GUI isn't frozen as indicated by mouse moving), Ctrl+Alt+F4 may open a terminal but it's not as direct to kernel it's not as guaranteed as SysRq commands.  You've indicated a non-existent but likely EOL Lubuntu though.  (*sysrq commands will only fail if disabled, or kernel has panic'd in which case nothing is working & screen should display panic dump*)

Comment: In what way are you building these boot images?  Are you using live-build or a different process?

Comment: I used one of the Matt gradient modified distributions, hearing from a friend that they are safe and work well

Comment: And it might have been 18.04 again I’m not able to get to my computer right now so I’m not sure the exact version

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   Any *respins* of Ubuntu are off-topic here, only *official* releaes are on-topic on this site  (SE *Unix & Linux* would be appropriate for *respins*).

Comment: Is it possible I’m partitioning wrong? 600mb of swap (I’ve upgraded to 6gb of ram) and the rest to Linux, I used the same partitions when installing mint and it worked, all be it very slow, so I’m trying to install the lighter weight Ubuntu versions